# How to read system variable java.rmi.server.hostname in JMeter script

Tags: jmeter

How to read system variable java.rmi.server.hostname in JMeter script using beanshell or groovy script. Appreciate if any one can help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) article it can be done as:

```
System.getProperty('java.rmi.server.hostname')
```

in [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

or in [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(System.getProperty('java.rmi.server.hostname'),)}
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)